# How to fix static/non-static conflict between .this and .setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to click on an info button in my recyclerview "planner" so I can see my (firestore) participants inside that particular event/day.

But I'm getting an error I cannot fix.
The biggest trouble I'm having is the fact im working within fragments. So copying Youtube doenst always work. + I'm new to coding and java.

[This want to make it non static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7twx.png)

but when I fix that:

[This wants to make it static again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgeQF.png)

*Inside LesAdapter*

```
public LesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        Lijst_Soort = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idLes);
        Lijst_Waar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idWaar);
        Lijst_Wanneer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idWanneer);
        btnInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);

        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(position !=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener !=null){
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position );
                }
            }
        });
}


public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
    }
```

**Inside HomeFragment** could using LesAdapter before .setOnItemClickListener be wrong?

```
LesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new LesAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            String wanneer = documentSnapshot.getString("Wanneer");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Deelnamelijst.class);
            intent.putExtra("Welke les", wanneer);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is what i was trying:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WR4QAiVuCw

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXoGG2XTjzU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that trying to call `LesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener` assumes that the `setOnItemClickListener` method is a static method and hence you can call it without creating an instance.

For your example, `setOnItemClickListener` is not a static method and hence to call it, you need an instance of `LesAdapter`. So use whatever instance you creating like

```
LesAdapter lesAdapter = new LesAdapter();

lesAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new LesAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            String wanneer = documentSnapshot.getString("Wanneer");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Deelnamelijst.class);
            intent.putExtra("Welke les", wanneer);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```